# Erro no Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou com um problema de conexão no Laravel ao executar uma query:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Arquivo database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'estoque_laravel'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'senhaacessodb'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Configurei o mesmo, e fica dando esse erro quando acessa a página que executa a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa alterar tambem o arquivo .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=zLzPMzs5W4FNNuguTmbG8M0iFqhIVnsP

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=estoque_laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=senhaacessodb

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Answer (score 2):

Não se configura por ai. As configurações ficam no arquivo `.env`, caso não exista, renome o arquivo `.env.example` para `.env`, dentro do arquivo irá conter as váriaveis:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Edite com as configurações atuais de seu banco.